# How to get files come from @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> post request from retrofit in WCF rest web service?

Tags: android, wcf, retrofit2

I am trying to send dynamic number of images to WCF web service. Method to send this request is like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST
Call<ResponseBody> sendImages(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> img, @Url String url,@Part("Content-Type") String contentType);
```

and Here is the implementation of method to send the images:

```
public void sendImages(List<EvaluationDetail> evaluationDetails, int evalId, final ResultCallBack resultCallBack){
    ApiService apiService=AppSingleton.getInstance(context).getApiService();
    String Url=ApiService.Post_images+"/"+evalId+"/";
    String questionIds="";
    List<MultipartBody.Part> parts=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<evaluationDetails.size();i++) {
        if(evaluationDetails.get(i).getImage()!=null) {
            File file = new File(evaluationDetails.get(i).getImage());
            if (file != null) {
                String partName = "img" + "_" + evalId + "_" + evaluationDetails.get(i).getQuestionID();
                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(null,file);
                parts.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile));
                questionIds=questionIds+String.valueOf(evaluationDetails.get(i).getQuestionID());
            }
        }
    }
    if(questionIds!=null)
    apiService.sendImages(parts,Url+questionIds,"multipart/form-data").enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            resultCallBack.onGetResult(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            resultCallBack.onFailedGet();
        }
    });


}
```

I don't know how the signature of function in wcf web service will look. I googled but I couldn't find the solution.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> why you setting `@Part("Content-Type") String contentType)`
>   dynamically ?

**Note:- `@Multipart` annotation is a Content Type in android and it support same properties as multipart/form-data(for web) do.**

Solution:- Remove `@Part("Content-Type") String contentType)` from your interface method.

Comment: thanks I remove it. But my main problem is in server side I don't how to get these List<MultipartBody.Part> files in wcf.

Comment: I have not write server side code :) I do not know How to get list of file from multipart request.

Comment: Try this for multiples files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296850/wcf-multipart-form-data-with-multiple-files